# Disagreed names of Bazel external dependencies in difference projects

Tags: bazel

Say there are two Bazel projects, they both depend on the Python package [six](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six).

Project A adds six with the name `six_1_10_0`:

```
new_http_archive(
    name = "six_1_10_0"
    ...
)

py_binary(
    name = "lib_a",
    deps = ["@six_1_10_0//:six"]
)
```

Project B adds six with the name `six_archive`.

```
new_http_archive(
    name = "six_archive"
    ...
)

py_binary(
    name = "lib_b",
    deps = ["@six_archive//:six"]
)
```

In my project, I depend on both A and B. Is there a way to let them use the same `six`?

Answer (score 1):

To change the `BUILD` file contents of a dependency, the simplest way I can think of is to use one of the `new_*` repository rules (e.g. [`new_git_repository`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/workspace.html#new_git_repository)). Using the `build_file` or `build_file_content` attribute to write a new `BUILD` file, write a new `py_binary` rule with its `deps` containing your canonical `@six` repository, and keeping all other attributes the same.

There isn't a straightforward way of doing this because Bazel makes no assumption on why Project A uses a different version of `six` compared to Project B.

The only way that Bazel knows that they're using the same version is if both `new_http_archive` rules specify the same `SHA` checksum. If they are the same checksum, you can use `--experimental_repository_cache=/some/path` to avoid downloading the same archive twice.